# Change Spotlight's Top Hit?

Tags: spotlight

Say I have two apps that match a search in spotlight (e.g. `utility`), it seems that Spotlight chooses the first application (sorted alphabetically) as the Top Hit. Is there any way to change this so that a different application appears on top?

Comment: If you switch to [LaunchBar](http://www.obdev.at/products/launchbar/index.html) it'll learn over a short period of time that when you type `utility` and select the second thing from the list that it should show you that thing first. Spotlight doesn't learn like that.

Comment: @Ian are you sure? it seems to me that sometimes, Spotlight was learning from my typing.

Comment: @Loïc Wolff not 100%. I couldn't find anything online that referenced Spotlight learning and that mirrored my experience which was it never did before I switched to LaunchBar. Example: I just tried to search for 's' in spotlight and the top hit it gave me was App Store despite me never, ever, ever using s to open App Store via Spotlight (I've haven't used Spotlight for a search for anything on this computer in many, many, many months).

Comment: I love QuickSilver's Set as Default command.

Comment: @Loïc Wolff, I have seen this behaviour too.

Answer (score 1):

Just use some other launcher. [Alfred](http://alfredapp.com) is also good at learning new associations. If for example you select "Disk Utility" after typing "ut", it will become the new default suggestion for "ut". Very low-maintenance.

You could also try [Apptivate](http://apptivateapp.com). It allows you to assign 2-letter shortcuts (like <kbd>⌥UT</kbd>) for launching applications.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a Tag to the item to see if that helps.

1. focus on the item and `cmd+I` to Get Info.
2. In the "Add Tags" field, add something like `utility`.

In my experience, the Tags seem to bump up the item in Spotlight.

Comment: This helped me, on Monterey. It was sorting automatically by mostUsed/lastUsed on Mojave. But the OS updates stopped working correctly. The tags help to mitigate what I see as a regression/buggy behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

One way is to drag the application into the Applications folder (if it isn't already there), and rename it so that it appears on top (e.g. `- My Utility`).